# Warning: Can't find ancestor for X copied from Y

Tags: mercurial

While running `hg convert` or `hg graft` I am seeing warnings similar to this:

`warning: can't find ancestor for 'service/src/main/java/com/vtlr/web/sql/package
-info.java' copied from 'service/src/main/java/com/vtlr/sql/package-info.java'!`

**What does the warning mean?**

Am I losing data in the conversion/graft? What can I do to correct the problem?

(I am running Mercurial 3.0)

Comment: Seems like the file has been renamed or moved. If you get that from a `graft`, the new parent is probably more different than you think.

Comment: @Vince: Okay, but what about `hg convert`? Why would I get the warning and does it mean I am losing any data?

Comment: I don't think you are loosing files, as you may even have duplicates, but those files will probably not be the same, if they were changed after the rename. Give the parameters of the `convert`, the reason for that command, and the frequency of its usage. The root cause for the warning is the same, but I don't know why the convert would show it, yet.

Comment: @Vince: I was invoking `hg convert source target --splicemap X` to swap one root for another. Now that I think about it, it's possible that this caused the files in question to lose the changeset that initially added them. In such a case, is `hg convert` smart enough to treat `modified` files without an ancestor as if they were `added` instead? I assume/hope they don't drop the files instead...